# How to inject '$modalInstance' into a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

In my application after I found out that a user is not logged in I want to open a modal dialog:

```
  .when('/showtask/:id', {templateUrl: 'Home/Template/showtask', resolve: ShowTaskCtrl.resolve, access: { allowAnonymous: false },
            resolve: {
        userAuthenticated: ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/api/Authentication/UserAuthenticated').then(function (data) {

                if (data.data != "null") {
                    deferred.resolve(data.data);
                }
                else {

                    var modalInstance = {
                        templateUrl: 'Home/Template/loginfailed',
                        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                        modalpart: ['modalpart', function (modalpart) {
                            return modalInstance;
                            }]
                    };
                    $modal.open(modalInstance);

                    deferred.reject();

                }   
            });
            return deferred.promise;

        }]

    }
```

Since it is happening on route change I have to inject a modalpart inside an instance and retrieve it in the controller.

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = WorkerApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ["$scope", "modalpart", function ($scope, modalpart) {
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Unknown provider: modalpartProvider <- modalpart

How can I solve this problem?

P.S. Original code which I am looking at is here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ (under modal)

Answer (score 9):

Had this problem for awhile as well. Although you didn't post your HTML, that is where my problem was. Make sure you do not name the controller in your DOM, this has already been taken care of for you in $modal.open().

Answer (score 8):

I've never had to use the `$modal` service inside a route change like what you are doing, so not sure how that will work. However just looking at your `$modal` code alone it looks wrong. The correct way should be:

```
var modalOptions = {
  templateUrl: 'Home/Template/loginfailed',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
};
$modal.open(modalOptions);
```

And then your controller definition:

```
WorkerApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',
  ["$scope", "$modalInstance", function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    // Do your stuff
  }]);
```

The `$modal` service will handle the injection of `$modalInstance` to your controller automatically, as per the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i still getting Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance... Are there any other way to achieve what i want?

Comment: But i really dont understand it, if i run console.log($modalInstance) it returns an object...

Comment: I suggest you create a minimal jsfiddle/plunker showing the error. Pretty sure it will get fixed then.

Comment: Also make sure you are running the latest 0.10.0 version of angular-ui

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Super frustrating. It works fine with the simple syntax "var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {" but I'm trying to code things the Google way :s

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, and I found that the controller I registed run twice!
thanks for @compguy ，I removed the controller name in the template .
I Successd!