# Closing A Modal in AngularJS UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Quite new with AngularJS (and AngularJS UI) and I am unable to close a modal window.

The HTML code as follows:

```
<div>
    <div data-ng-show="agencies || agencies.length > 0">
        <div>
            <h3>
                Agencies
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="" data-ng-click="showModalAddAgency()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span>&nbsp;Add</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    'use strict';

        app.controller('agencyController', function ($scope, $modal, agenciesDataService) {
            $scope.agencies = [];
            $scope.agency = null;
            init();

            function init() {
                getAgencies();
            };

        function getAgencies() {
                var onResponse = function (results) {
                    $scope.agencies = results.data;
                };

                var onError = function (error) {
                    alert(error.message);
                };

                agenciesDataService.getAgencies()
                    .then(onResponse, onError);
            };

        $scope.showModalAddAgency = function () {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/agencydetail.html',
                    controller: 'agencyController',
                    backdrop: 'static'
                });
            };

        $scope.addAgency = function addAgency() {
                var currentAgency = this.agency;

                var onResponse = function (results) {
                    currentAgency.Id = results.data.Id;
                    currentAgency.Name = results.data.Name;
                    currentAgency.AgencyPortalAccountId = results.data.AgencyPortalAccountId;
                    $scope.agencies.push(currentAgency);
                    currentAgency = {};

                    // HOW TO CLOSE THE MODAL FROM HERE? WHAT FUNCTION DO I CALL?
                };

                var onError = function (error) {
                    //alert(error.message);
                }

                agenciesDataService.addAgency(currentAgency)
                    .then(onResponse, onError);
            };

        });
```

Pretty much, after making the POST request, I want to close the modal window, but I don't have any idea how. Not sure how I can reference the modal window which I opened.

Any insight appreciated.

Update:
My modal's html includes an Save and Cancel button.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-primary normal-button"
            ng-click="addAgency()">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$dismiss()" style="width:100px;">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The modal does close when I hit the Cancel button. What I want to achieve is being able to close the modal when the addAgency function is completed.

Comment: see the close and dismiss methods shown in example in docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save your modal instance in the $scope so that you have a reference to it later.

So you'd init your `$scope.modalInstance = null;` at the top.

Then you'd open your modal like this:

```
$scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'app/views/agencydetail.html',
    controller: 'agencyController',
    backdrop: 'static'
});
```

To close, you would then call `$scope.modalInstance.close();` (which would go where you have your `// HOW TO CLOSE THE MODAL FROM HERE? WHAT FUNCTION DO I CALL?` comment.

Here's a plunkr that shows how to do it: [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/b8KLQ/3/)

Comment: If I code the things as you have suggested, what happens is that the application hangs. (Chrome Kill Pages dialog pops up). I did $scope.modalInstance = function(){ $modal.open({});}; and it did open up the modal but still, issuing the $scope.modalInstance.close(); throws an undefined is not a function error.

Comment: Try $scope.modalInstance.$close()

Comment: Also, try '$dismiss()' $scope.modalInstance.$dismiss()

Comment: I've added an example plunkr that works - try it out.

Comment: I've found out the issue, thanks in part to your suggested solution.

Comment: Excellent! What was it?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Got it through the $modalInstance.close() which I passed to my controller.

Answer (score 1):

To close your modal you have 2 functions : "close" and "dismiss".

Let say that the end of your modal html file looks like that :

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="button" class="submit" value="Save" ng-click="ok()" />
    <input type="button" class="cancel" value="Cancel" ng-click="cancel()" />
</div>
```

All you have to write in your modal controller is that :

```
$scope.cancel = function(){
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
$scope.ok = function(){
    // you can pass anything you want value object or reference object
    $modalInstance.close("clicked ok"); 
};
```

And if you want to know if the user clicked on "cancel" or "ok" you have to change your function "showModalAddAgency" like that :

```
$scope.showModalAddAgency = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
         templateUrl: 'app/views/agencydetail.html',
         controller: 'agencyController',
         backdrop: 'static'
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (resultOk) {
         // OK
    }, function (resultCancel) {
         // CANCEL
    });
};
```

I hope my answer fit you.

Have a nice day !

Comment: In my modal, when the user clicks the OK button, there are some additional process being made (hence, in my original question, I am asking what code to add in my $scope.addAgency function).

Comment: One solution would be to have to basic function "ok" and "cancel" in your modal.
If the user clicks on "cancel" you "dismiss" .
If the user clicks on "ok" you close.

And in the "showModalAddAgency", you make a call to AddAgency if the user clicked on "ok".

Comment: But I wouldn't want to close the modal outright until knowing that the addAgency call is successful...

Comment: Please try this :
inject the service "$modalInstance" on your controller.
In AddAgency, where you put your comment : "// HOW TO CLOSE THE MODAL FROM HERE? WHAT FUNCTION DO I CALL?",
replace it by :
"$modalInstance.close(); "

If the user clicks on cancel, the modal dismiss
If the user clicks on addAgency the modal will be close only if the request succeeded.

Comment: Got an error: ReferenceError: $modalInstance is not defined

Comment: Try the first answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055700/how-to-inject-modalinstance-inside-a-controller

Comment: Tried the codes as per what you referred but still unable to get the modal to close. I tried variations of $modal.close(), $modalinstance.close, $modal.dismiss(), etc. but to no avail.